# How to pre load images in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I loaded XML data (including images, text,...) from server and display that data through tableview.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"user_id"])
{
    Myxml.str_user_id = currentNodeContent;
}

else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"username"])
{
    Myxml.str_username = currentNodeContent;

}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"avatar"])
{
    Myxml.str_avatar=currentNodeContent;
    Myxml.imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentNodeContent]];

}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"full_name"])
{
    Myxml.str_full_name=currentNodeContent;

}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"cups"])
{
    Myxml.str_cups=currentNodeContent; 
}
//--------Record End-------
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"record"])
{
    [RecordArray addObject:Myxml];
    [Myxml release];
    Myxml = nil;        
}

[currentNodeContent release];
currentNodeContent = nil;
currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
```

}

Now, In main view controller I collect all data in NSMutableArray named "LabelArray" in init method

```
Connection=[[NetworkConnection alloc]initConnection];

if (Connection.isReachable)
{
    XmlDetail=[[TopPickerXML alloc]init];

    LabelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:XmlDetail.RecordArray];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Network connection unavailable..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

And In Table view in cellForRowAtIndexPath, I display image like this

```
img_BuddyAvtar=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
img_BuddyAvtar.frame=CGRectMake(10, 5, 120, 105);
img_BuddyAvtar.image=[UIImage imageWithData:TopPicker_record.imageData];
img_BuddyAvtar.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[View_TableCell addSubview:img_BuddyAvtar];
```

Now ,My problem is when I load this view it takes time to load and then displays all data including my text and images.How can i Preload images so that it would take less time to load my table view?

Answer (score 0):

You should have to cache image.

1. Add SDWebImage to your project.
2. import `<SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` header
3. add below code at `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

   ```
   [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your image URL"]
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
   ```

Comment: yes it will. you just need to pass url and placeholder image. that's it :)